# Pandas reset index after operations on rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know if there is a way to assign new **.loc** values to a dataframe in order to index this row. 
I was writing code where I was indexing rows by the **.loc[]**, but now I have randomly shuffled the dataframe in to two sets and so when I index the row by **.loc[]**, i get a key error as the row might be in the other dataset.

I want to be able to assign a new .loc[] index to the data right after I shuffle so I can still index as I always have.

Example, I have a dataframe:

```
          length    height...                  water      type
    4     15.85  14.7240  ...               0.173     orange
    92    20.06  17.3565  ...               0.171     orange
    155   22.71  15.8040  ...               0.169     apple
    142   11.76  12.2355  ...               0.175     pear
    91    20.33  16.0785  ...               0.175      apple
```

The index given is displayed on the left (i.e 4 to 91), I want to change these index values to what I want to assign them, which is in sequential order (i.e 0 to 4). So that when I call .loc[0] it will return the first row and not give me a KeyError as that row is in another dataset

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)? Though it really depends on exactly what you need to do with the row that doesn't exist. You should be able to [Set with Enlargment](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) regardless of whether the index exists.

Comment: @ALollz I have updated the question to provide an example, im not sure reindex is working

Comment: Okay, I get it. You want `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thanks very much @ALollz , that worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Pandas documentation:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([('bird', 389.0),
...                    ('bird', 24.0),
...                    ('mammal', 80.5),
...                    ('mammal', np.nan)],
...                   index=['falcon', 'parrot', 'lion', 'monkey'],
...                   columns=('class', 'max_speed'))
>>> df
         class  max_speed
falcon    bird      389.0
parrot    bird       24.0
lion    mammal       80.5
monkey  mammal        NaN
```

using reset_index with drop parameter:

```
>>> df.reset_index(drop=True)
    class  max_speed
0    bird      389.0
1    bird       24.0
2  mammal       80.5
3  mammal        NaN
```